# How to look for multiple data sets for use in Shiny Interactive Document in RStudio?

Tags: r, shiny

I have started learning about Shiny Interactive documents and am not a programmer so please pardon my ignorance.
This is based on rmarkdown version 2 website 'Advanced' topics page. I have the RStudio version 0.98.1028.
I am trying to display the `head` of vectors `a` or `b` in the shiny doc. Here's what I did:

````
```{r two, echo = FALSE}

a <- 1:10
b <- 13:20
a
b
selectInput("dataset2", "Choose Dataset:", c('a', 'b'))

activeDataset2 <- reactive({
  get(input$dataset2)
})

renderTable({
  head(activeDataset2(), 5)
})

```
````

Upon clicking `Run Document`, I get the Error `no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"`.
In the example on the website, an argument `pos` is used to look for the data sets. I don't know how to use that in this context. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`renderTable` uses `xtable`to produce its tables:

```
a <- 1:10
> library(xtable)
> xtable(a)
Error in UseMethod("xtable") : 
  no applicable method for 'xtable' applied to an object of class "c('integer', 'numeric')"
```

so the problem here is that xtable requires an object passed to it with an xtable method defined:

```
> methods(xtable)
 [1] xtable.anova*           xtable.aov*             xtable.aovlist*        
 [4] xtable.coxph*           xtable.data.frame*      xtable.glm*            
 [7] xtable.lm*              xtable.matrix*          xtable.prcomp*         
[10] xtable.summary.aov*     xtable.summary.aovlist* xtable.summary.glm*    
[13] xtable.summary.lm*      xtable.summary.prcomp*  xtable.table*          
[16] xtable.ts*              xtable.zoo*
```

You could change your output to a `data.frame`

```
activeDataset2 <- reactive({
  out <- get(input$dataset2)
  `names<-`(data.frame(out), input$dataset2)
})
```

or you can write an appropriate xtable method for objects of class `"c('integer', 'numeric')"`